# What is the right merge script in the eclipse of using tfvc on MacOS?

Tags: eclipse, tfvc, beyondcompare4

How to use beyond compare as the merge tool in eclipse.

I am using TFVC on MacOS by eclipse integration plug-in.

My merge tool edit scrpts:

```
"/Applications/Beyond Compare.app/Contents/MacOS/bcomp" %1 %2  %3 %4 -lefttitle=%6 -centertitle=%7 -righttitle=%8  -outputtitle=%9
```

I use beyond compare as my compare tool in eclipse work well and the script is :

```
"/Applications/Beyond Compare.app/Contents/MacOS/bcomp" %1 %2  -lefttitle=%6 -righttitle=%7
```

What's wrong with my merge script?
What is the right merge script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

```
"/Applications/Beyond Compare.app/Contents/MacOS/bcomp" %1 %2  %3 %4 -lefttitle=%6 -centertitle=%7 -righttitle=%8  -outputtitle=%9
```

To

```
"/Applications/Beyond Compare.app/Contents/MacOS/bcomp" %1 %2  %3  %4   -outputtitle=%2
```

When I use the Beyond Compare to solve one file conflict, then the file dismisses in the conflict area. The conflicting file is solved.

This is the result which I want.